# Are Dark Templars visible during warp-in if you have warp gates?

Tags: starcraft-2

I know that units being warped in can be attacked as soon as their visage begins to appear on the screen.  Is this visage cloaked for dark templars?

Comment: @tzenes, I expect you're already busy creating an answer including pictures.

Comment: @tzenes at first I thought you were being facetious about taking screen shots of undetected cloaked units from the opponents perspective. Of course, @Raven pulled through with what looks like a custom map

Comment: to be fair, I tried to do it via. a replay of a custom match against a computer player, but the AI liked photocannons too much.

Comment: I trivially knew the answer, but I wanted a better answer which had pictures, and since I wasn't at my home computer I put the comment so someone else would put the picture up. Its easy for things like this to be misreported on wiki's (Infestor Range being a prime example) and its best if we have first party information.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Resorath and the wiki are correct; Dark Templar indeed are cloaked while warping in.

In this screenshot, the two sentries ignore the Dark Templar during it's warp in:
[image]

But once we add a Raven to the mix, the sentries switch their focus to the templar soon after the warp in initiates:
[image]

Comment: Good screens, dark templars warping in via a warp prism into the back of your base is pretty annoying, especially since a deployed warp prism is still considered "flying".

Answer (score 6):

According to [this](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_templar_%28StarCraft_II%29) they cloak while warping in.